# Which assertion library for Java has the best integration with Allure Reports?

Tags: automated-tests, junit5, allure, assertj

I'm using Allure Reports to provide test results on my automated tests. However, I'm noticing that assertions are not showing up as step in the reports. I would like to know which assertions library has best integration with Allure, so that when I use these assertions, they appear in the report.

I'm using JUnit5 with RestAssured for my automated tests.

If the answer is none, then would the best course of action be to create my own assertion library to add the @Step annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Allure provides integrations with [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) and [Hamcrest](https://hamcrest.org/) assertions libraries. See `allure-assertj` and `allure-hamcrest` Maven modules.